# How to print lines in splitlines by indentation?

Tags: python, split, indentation

I have string:

```
text = '''TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4'''
```

I want to split this string by indentations and add them to a list. Here is my current code:

```
nr_lines = 0
indent_dict = {}
for line in summary1.splitlines(True):
    print(line)
    print("------------------------------")
    nr_lines+=1
    whitespaces_count = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
    indent_dict[nr_lines] = whitespaces_count
print(indent_dict)

list_of_values = []

# Removed first key with value (indent) = 0
indent_dict_without = dict(indent_dict)
key = 1
del indent_dict_without[key]

# Adding values from dict to list
for key, value in indent_dict_without.items():
    list_of_values.append(value)
print(list_of_values)

# Finding minimum value
x = min(list_of_values)

list_of_small = []

for nr in list_of_values:
    if nr == x:
        list_of_small.append(nr)

print(list_of_small)

# Finding which line have all smallest indent
n = 0
key_1 = []
for key, value in indent_dict.items():
    if value == list_of_small[n]:
        key_1.append(key)
print(key_1)
```

Output is:

```
{1: 0, 2: 12, 3: 8, 4: 12, 5: 12, 6: 12, 7: 12, 8: 8, 9: 12, 10: 12, 11: 8, 12: 12, 13: 12} # dict with line and value (indent)
[12, 8, 12, 12, 12, 12, 8, 12, 12, 8, 12, 12] # list with indents
[8, 8, 8] # the smallest indents
[3, 8, 11] # lines for smallest indents
```

Now, I don't know how to split and add those 4 parts as elements of list:

```
list = ['TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1',
        'TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2',
        'TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3',
        'TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4']
```

Should I create a new variable and add lines one by one until a new indent?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your goal is here. Could you post an expected output, please?

Comment: Hi! As you can see, my final output should be list of elements. You can see this in list called "list". Each Text1/2/3/4 is a different element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to split the text in parargraphs based on the lines with the smallest indentation.

The way I would approach tis is as follows. I would create a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with as key the nummer of spaces that make up the indentation and as value a list with all the indexes of the lines that have this indentation count:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = '''TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4'''

def count_indentation(line):
    return len(line) - len(line.lstrip())

lines = text.splitlines(keepends=False)
indent_dict = defaultdict(list)
for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if count_indentation(line) > 0:
        indent_dict[count_indentation(line)].append(idx)
```

Now `indent_dict` looks like:

```
defaultdict(list, {8: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12], 4: [2, 7, 10]})
```

Next, we take the smallest key to find the indexes of the relevant lines:

```
smallest_indent = min(indent_dict)
line_idexes_smallest_indents = indent_dict[smallest_indent]
```

The result of `line_idexes_smallest_indents` is `[2, 7, 10]`. Indexing is zero-based so that is why my indexes are all one less then your result. Now we need to partition our original text according to these indexes.

```
def partition(lines, indices):
    return [''.join(lines[i:j]) for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])]

partition(lines, line_idexes_smallest_indents)
```

Result:

```
['TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1',
 '    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2',
 '    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3',
 '    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4']
```

Comment: Hello! Your function work very well but I have one question. What if string "text" will have only one line? In this case it is possible to create conditional statement to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest I came up with. I'm sure there are more elegant solutions

```
text = '''TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4
    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4'''


lines = text.split('\n')
# Count spaces in each line
indent_lst = [line.count(' ') for line in text.splitlines(True)]
# Find where indentation changes
indices = []
for idx in range(len(indent_lst[1:])): # Start at second element in list
    # Here I assume, that the indentation is constant. A change from more spaces to fewer spaces means,
    # that a new block has started
    if indent_lst[idx-1] > indent_lst[idx]: # Look back at previous element and compare with current
        indices.append(idx)

final_lst = []
# Use slicing to append from block to block
for idx in range(len(indices)):
    if indices.index(indices[idx]) == (len(indices) -1 ): # Take care of last block
        final_lst.append(''.join(lines[indices[idx]:]))
    else:
        final_lst.append(''.join(lines[indices[idx]:indices[idx+1]])) # Add block to final list
print(final_lst)
```

Here is the result:

```
['TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText1', '    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText2', '    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText3', '    TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4        TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText4']
```

I hope this helps you already and feel free to ask if you have questions!

Comment: Hello! I have the same question as above solution. It is possible to execute your function only for one line?

Comment: If you have only one line, why would youlike to split at all?

Comment: I want only append string to list :)